# Python fails to import Extractor from selectrolib?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to follow up a tutorial on [webscraping](https://medium.com/scrapehero/tutorial-how-to-scrape-amazon-product-details-using-python-56d40e7503b7). And while I successfully compiled
Selectorlib via GitHub repo, when I try to compile the code listed in the webpage:

```
from selectorlib import Extractor
import requests 
import json 
import argparseargparser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
argparser.add_argument('url', help='Amazon Product Details URL')# Create an Extractor by reading     from the YAML file
e = Extractor.from_yaml_file('selectors.yml')user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36 Edge/12.246'
headers = {'User-Agent': user_agent}# Download the page using requests
args = argparser.parse_args()
r = requests.get(args.url, headers=headers)
# Pass the HTML of the page and create 
data = e.extract(r.text)
# Print the data 
print(json.dumps(data, indent=True))
```

i get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "test.py", line 1, in
>
> from selectorlib import Extractor
>
> ImportError: cannot import name 'Extractor' from 'selectorlib' (unknown location)

What could cause this problem? I tried googling it, importing only selectorlib , installing extractor from pip, importing only exctractor, nothing seems to fix this issue, did something changed from the tutorial release to now?

EDIT:
After reinstalling selectorlib i get a diffrent error:

> from selectorlib import Extractor
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selectorlib/**init**.py", line 9, in
>
> from .selectorlib import Extractor  # noqa:F401
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selectorlib/selectorlib.py", line 33
>
> def from_yaml_string(cls, yaml_string: str, formatters=None):

The error is indicating at: **yaml_string:**
I am running python on Raspberry Buster (RPI 3B+)

Comment: Which command did you use to install selectorlib?

Answer (score 1):

I have tried using `pip install selectorlib` and import of Extractor class works fine for me. You might want to execute the following steps to get rid off this issue

1. Run again the installation command like this `python setup.py install --record install_files.txt`
2. For removal of package, if you are using Linux use `xargs rm -rf < install_files.txt` or Windows use powershell command `Get-Content install_files.txt | ForEach-Object {Remove-Item $_ -Recurse -Force}`
3. Try installing the package again with command `pip install selectorlib`

Hope this should clear the issue as it fresh installs the package with help of wheel files.

Comment: I see that you are using Python 2.7 to run your web scraping code. The function 
``` def from_yaml_string(cls, yaml_string: str, formatters=None): ``` uses [PEP 3107](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/) implementation which is interpreted from Python3. You might wanna upgrade your existing python version from 2.7 to 3.x, if that is a problem then make use of virtualenv to do so

Comment: When I use python3 to execute the code I get the same first error that Extractor can`t be imported from selectorlib.

Comment: Can you describe the environment that you are using to make this work.

Comment: I do not understand your question. I am following the tutorial i linked on begining of the question.

Comment: I mean which Operating System are you using and How did you install selectorlib library. Were you able to import the library explicitly from the interpreter.

Comment: I am running Rasbian Buster, I installed it via pip, when importing via interpreter I get the following error: ImportError: cannot import name 'Extractor' from 'selectorlib' (unknown location)